# How to make a DIV inherit it's "em" value from its parent's parent

Tags: html, css, elasticlayout

We all know that the elastic layout "em" value for a given object is relative to the object's parent, e.g.:

`<div id="div1" style="font-size:1em;">`
 `<p>Hello</p>`
 `<div id="div2" style="font-size:0.5em;">`
  `<p>Hello</p>`
   `<div id="div3" style="font-size:0.5em;">`
    `<p>Hello</p>`
   `</div>`
  `</div>`
 `</div>`

But is it possible to make a subordinate DIV "reset" it's em value, or get its value from a parent higher up the chain?

Basically, I have some nested DIVs, and I want one of the inner ones to use the document's own em value.  Using 1em is no good, as one of the DIV's parents already uses a fractional value.

Thanks in advance

Simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Update*: Since this answer was originally written, a new unit has been added to CSS.

`rem` is the [root em](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#font-relative-lengths) and is:

> Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element.

This is "the document's own em value".

---

No, it isn't. font-sizes set with the `em` unit are explicitly relative to the parent element's font-size.

The closest you can come is to know all the changes and account for that when calculating.

e.g. since the #div2 has a font-size of 0.5em, to make #div3 have the same font-size as #div1 you would need to set `font-size: 2em`

Other lengths (with as `width` values) are relative to the current element's font-size, and you would have to make similar calculations for those.

Comment: Thanks David.  I thought as much.  I was hoping to avoid having to perform reciprocal calculations.  Vote++ and answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider the use of CSS classes instead of styles, as this will solve your problem.  Is there a reason you are using style instead of a CSS Class?

```
<div id="div1">
<p class="font1em">Hello</p>
<div id="div2">
<p class="fonthalfem">Hello</p>
<div id="div3">
<p class="fonthalfem">Hello</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think there's any difference wether `font-size` is set using element styles or css classes. Font size expressed in `em`s is relative either way.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  The above example was just to demonstrate the problem; I do generally use classes.  As Athari said, the problem remains!

Comment: I'm saying changing the thought process from trying to make something inherit from a parent.parent.parent.. etc etc which doesn't work, to just using a CSS class that has the size you want on the DIV you want.

Comment: — em units still give font sizes relative to the parent element. If you're suggesting "Use a non-relative unit" then it makes no difference if you do that inline or further up the cascade.

Comment: I've modified my answer to what I believe should have been done instead.